# How to customize google maps directions not to show waypoints

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My problem is that waypoints are highlighted in directions list like: start to waypoint 1, waypoint 1 to waypoint 2, ...

here is an example how it is looking: http://www.ridersguide.co.uk/Ride_721

I'd like to show start and instructions how to reach destination points without showing waypoints.

Do you have some idea?

Answer (score 6):

you can supress the markers with these settings

```
 var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            suppressMarkers: true,
            suppressInfoWindows: true,

       });
```

Comment: you're right, but I meant disable waypoints from directions LIST including instructions how to go.

Answer (score 0):

@Ramesh K's answer is generally correct. However, in this way, you also kill the marker of start point and end point. You need to create to marker by yourself then.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have the defaults in the Waypoint for your api calls.

[Look here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsWaypoint) for a suggestion to remove waypoints as a 'layover' in your trip